# how to set memory limit by percent in cgroups

Tags: cgroup

In my Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS I need to set memory usage limit to 50%, but inside /sys/fs/cgroup/memory I see only "*limit_in_bytes" files.

Is it possible to limit memory usage by percent in cgroups?

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to do this?

Comment: @heynnema I assume in order to limit the total amount of memory apache can eat. Sometimes apache runs PHP code via `libapache2-mod-php` so if there is a lot of traffic then apache can eat tons of memory.